# 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "flip_fluids_addon" not found'

Tags: rendering, add-on, fluid-simulation

I was trying to attached the ff code to my scene via Text Editor to call/enable said add-on but encountered error in title.

```
import addon_utils
addon_utils.enable("flip_fluids_addon")
```

I just need to make sure the scene has the add-on enable for renderfarms.
Having issues w/ flip render via renderfarm.

Comment: works for me. Maybe you did not install it before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error looks related to a bug in Blender which occurs when trying to enable an addon through script or command line: https://developer.blender.org/T87629

If this is the case, the full error message from the Blender System Console would look something like this:

```
Exception in module register(): C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.93\scripts\addons\flip_fluids_addon\__init__.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\blender-2.93.6\2.93\scripts\modules\addon_utils.py", line 386, in enable
    mod.register()
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.93\scripts\addons\flip_fluids_addon\__init__.py", line 145, in register
    properties.register()
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.93\scripts\addons\flip_fluids_addon\properties\__init__.py", line 72, in register
    preferences_properties.register()
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.93\scripts\addons\flip_fluids_addon\properties\preferences_properties.py", line 310, in register
    preferences = vcu.get_blender_preferences(bpy.context).addons[id_name].preferences
KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "flip_fluids_addon" not found'
```

#### Workaround #1: Alternate addon enable script

Instead of using the *addon_utils* module, use the *preferences.addon_enable* operator, which does not seem to trigger this bug.

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.preferences.addon_enable(module="flip_fluids_addon")
```

#### Workaround #2: Update the FLIP Fluids addon

Due to this bug, the FLIP Fluids addon added a workaround to bypass this error in more recent versions. You will need to update the FLIP Fluids addon to version 1.1.0 or later in order to use the *addon_utils* script.

Comment: Workaround#1 worked!
Attaching the script and making sure it runs when blend file was opened did the trick.

Thank you.